# Enable / disable the automatic reload of shiny

Tags: python, py-shiny

I have a shiny express app like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd
from shiny import reactive, req, render

from shiny.express import input, render, ui

# variables
ui.page_opts(title="Range Rover", fillable=True)
...
```

It runs in `VS Code` which works fine. However, I'd like to prevent the automatic reload within some file setting but was unable to find the relevant documentation (if this is possible after all). So, the question: how to stop the automatic reload?

Comment: @Jan: Well, despite the beautiful given name, the edit was not very helpful ;-)

Comment: Because `py-shiny` has a smaller reach than `shiny`? ;-) I know, but the `shiny` tag description clearly says "... For the Python Shiny package, use the tag [py-shiny] instead.".

Comment: @Jan: I don't really care, the main thing is that the question is answered.